# How to create a funnel view in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe that has the following structure.

```
ProdID         Date                    class          price        set
PD-10011       2021-05-01 10:12:16     Regular        1000         ZR
PD-10712       2021-05-02 18:12:06     Premium        1000         ZR
PD-10213       2021-05-02 16:02:59     Premium        1000         ZR
PD-10814       2021-05-03 17:12:06     Premium        1000         RS
PD-10315       2021-05-04 19:10:11     Other          1000         RR
PD-10616       2021-05-04 13:18:14     Expired        1000         ZR
PD-10617       2021-05-04 15:14:19     Regular        1000         ZR
```

I need to create a funnel view by utilizing the data frame considering the following conditions:

May-21, the month should be auto-populating based on Date. If there are records of multiple months then it should be sequenced by month in descending month order. Here, `Total` is count of Total unique ProdID for that particular month. `Regular` is the count and sum of those ProdID having class as "Regular" and similar logic for the "Premium" row. The `miscellaneous` row is a count of ProdID having classes other than "Regular" and "Premium". `RS (Premium)` is count and sum of those where the class is "Premium" along with set as "RS".

```
May-21           Count of ProdID       Percentage Count       Sum of Price        Percentage Sum
Total            7                     100.00%                7000                100.00%
Regular          2                     28.57%                 2000                28.57%
Premium          3                     42.85%                 3000                42.85%
miscellaneous    2                     28.57%                 2000                28.57%
RS (Premium)     1                     33.33%                 1000                33.33%
```

Comment: you should focus your question one one problem only.

Answer (score 0):

On StackOverflow it is expected that you show your own attempts to solve the problem. Having said that, this should get you started:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(janitor)

df <- tibble::tribble(
                                      ~ProdID,                 ~Date,    ~class, ~price, ~set,
                                   "PD-10011", "2021-05-01 10:12:16", "Regular",  1000L, "ZR",
                                   "PD-10712", "2021-05-02 18:12:06", "Premium",  1000L, "ZR",
                                   "PD-10213", "2021-05-02 16:02:59", "Premium",  1000L, "ZR",
                                   "PD-10814", "2021-05-03 17:12:06", "Premium",  1000L, "RS",
                                   "PD-10315", "2021-05-04 19:10:11",   "Other",  1000L, "RR",
                                   "PD-10616", "2021-05-04 13:18:14", "Expired",  1000L, "ZR",
                                   "PD-10617", "2021-05-04 15:14:19", "Regular",  1000L, "ZR"
                                   )
df %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd_hms(Date)) %>% 
  filter(Date %within% interval("2021-05-01", "2021-05-31")) %>%
  mutate(class = case_when(class == "Premium" & set == "RS" ~ "RS (Premium)",
                           class != "Premium" & class != "Regular" ~ "miscellaneous",
                           class == "Premium" ~ "Premium",
                           class == "Regular" ~ "Regular")) %>% 
  group_by(class, price) %>% 
  summarise(count_of_prod_ID = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(`Sum of Price` = count_of_prod_ID * price,
         `Count (%)` = round((count_of_prod_ID / 7)*100, 2)) %>%
  janitor::adorn_totals() %>% 
  select(-c(price)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(count_of_prod_ID))
#>        class count_of_prod_ID Sum of Price Count (%)
#>         Total                7         7000    100.00
#> miscellaneous                2         2000     28.57
#>       Premium                2         2000     28.57
#>       Regular                2         2000     28.57
#>  RS (Premium)                1         1000     14.29
```

Comment: How to divide `RS (Premium)` count with `Premium` count in last row.

Comment: You want to count `RS (Premium)` as a `Premium`? But then all of your percentages will be off

Comment: Not for all, I just need it for last row.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. If you count the `RS (Premium)` as a `Premium` (i.e. count it twice) then nothing will add up, e.g. if `RS (Premium) = 1` and `Premium = 3`, then your total prod count will be 8... I'm not sure how to summarise a subset of rows, but then print all rows. Sorry.